# Is it possible to query an index in a MySQL/MariaDB database?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I know that you can tell if an index exists in MySQL with a statement like

```
SHOW INDEX FROM table1;
```

but is it possible to actually query the index to check the state of the index, e.g. something along the lines of

```
SELECT * FROM <index_name>
```

And get a result set like you would from a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot query an index in MySQL or MariaDB.

You can see statistics of an index - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/statistics-table.html, but you cannot peek into the index.

Comment: `SELECT a, b FROM tbl;` will read only the index if the index is `INDEX(a, b)`.  This is confirmed if `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` says "Using index".